# Can't change Input component using plotly dash callback

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I think there might be a something broken in changing input text using a callback.

Here's an example script showing the problem.

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Input(
        id='an_input',
        value='Nothing done yet!',
        type='text'),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='my-dropdown',
        options=[
            {'label': 'New York City', 'value': 'NYC'},
            {'label': 'Montreal', 'value': 'MTL'},
            {'label': 'San Francisco', 'value': 'SF'}
        ],
        value='NYC'
    ),
    html.Div(id='output-container')
])

@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('an_input', 'value'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('my-dropdown', 'value')])
def update_input_component(value):
    print('Trying to change input value')
    return 'You have selected "{}"'.format(value)


@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('output-container', 'children'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('my-dropdown', 'value')])
def update_output(value):
    return 'You have selected "{}"'.format(value)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

When I change the dropdown menu, I'd expect the input text to be updated, but it isn't!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're using an input component for your output. There are two things you can do here. Either you can update the `placeholder` value for your `dcc.Input` component, or you can change it to something else, like `html.P` or `html.Div` to hold your output. I prefer the second one, because it looks like the purpose of that component in your layout is simply to hold output from the dropdown, not to act as an input at all. Here is a working example.

```py
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div(
        id='text-output',
        children='Your text here'),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='my-dropdown',
        options=[
            {'label': 'New York City', 'value': 'NYC'},
            {'label': 'Montreal', 'value': 'MTL'},
            {'label': 'San Francisco', 'value': 'SF'}
        ],
        value='NYC'
    ),
    html.Div(id='output-container')
])

@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('text-output', 'children'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('my-dropdown', 'value')])
def update_input_component(value):
    print('Trying to change input value')
    return 'You have selected "{}"'.format(value)


@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('output-container', 'children'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('my-dropdown', 'value')])
def update_output(value):
    return 'You have selected "{}"'.format(value)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

If you really want to use the `dcc.Input`, then you can change the code like this. Make the input:

```py
dcc.Input(
        id='an_input',
        value='',
        placeholder='Enter text...',
        type='text'),
```

and make your callback's output like this:
`dash.dependencies.Output('an_input', 'placeholder'),`

Comment: In my application, I want to have an input component with some parameter, let's call it 'a'. I want to have a dropdown menu that has different options for prepopulating 'a' with a value, which then the user can change if they want.

Comment: In that case, I would suggest using different tools for that job. The `input` is really more for the user to enter whatever text they want. If you want to have them work with set values, I think radio buttons or a dropdown are the best bet. You already have the dropdown, why not use that value in your callback instead of adding the `input` as a middleman?